# What is the proper way to synchronize/secure sensitive data in my application?

Tags: node.js, security, electron, credentials

### Background

I've been out of the web app development realm for a few years and I've recently come back into it. There are a few questions I have about best security practices for performing the following tasks.

I'm developing an electron (node.js) application that will authenticate user credentials using my remote application server. On my server I have a MySQL database which will store the usual assortment of user account and application data. Additionally, the electron application will have a local sqlite database that I will periodically be updated to keep things in sync with the remote MySQL server. The Sqlite database is there to allow the application to continue to function should the electron app be used in an offline environment or in case the remote server goes down. I intend the application to be online first with an offline fallback.

Once the user authenticates in the electron app, the application will allow the user to do their work, and when the user is done, their work will be submitted to a 3rd party by posting that work to the 3rd party's API. The first time a user logs in, they will be asked to authenticate with the 3rd party API using OAuth2 and an api access token will be given by the 3rd party upon successful completion of this authentication procedure. This token will be stored in the remote MySQL database as well as the local sqlite database.

Here's the kicker. There will be multiple machines running this electron application so keeping everything in sync between all of these installations is a necessity as the same user may be using any one of these machines on a given day.

### The Questions

With the background information out of the way, here are my questions:

1. If I hash and salt user passwords prior to storing them in the database: is SHA-512 still a secure hash, or is there another algorithm that is better?
2. The 3rd party API token is essentially the user's password to accessing the 3rd party API. I intend to treat it as such and give it the same treatment as I would a password. Since hashing is one-way and therefore not an option, how could I best encrypt the API token for storage in the database? My current thought is to use AES with a long randomly generated string that is stored in my server application's configuration file as the secret key. In this case, if the database is breached, the secret key would not be included with the data. To acquire the secret key the server itself would have to be broken into. Is this the best way of going about this?
3. Upon application startup or when manually triggered, the local electron app will query my remote server to determine if there has been any changes to the database since the local sqlite database was last updated. If there are changes and a local update is needed, the remote server will send back a response with all the things that have changed (probably in a JSON format) since the last update. The connection between the local application and the remote server will be encrypted using TLS (https). Is this sufficient to protect the data exchange (which contains password hashes and the like) between the local application and the remote server or should the JSON object be further encrypted? Is this even a good way to go about syncing data?

I appreciate any and all help. I'm a bit out of touch with some of the current best practices, and this is my first actual production application in a long while, so I want to make sure things are done properly.